# Akka FSM: State Transition to same state doesn't happen as expected

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

In an implementation of an FSM (old story: modeling an Elevator/Lift), I am trying to see if I can test whether the FSM follows a transition from and to the same State. It seems, it is not happening, but that surprises me because according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356655/fsm-actor-is-not-firing-ontransition-after-goto-to-the-same-state?rq=1) discussion on StackOverFlow, the fix is available in Akka 2.4.x.

Here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
  class LiftCarriageWithMovingState extends Actor
  with FSM[LiftState,LiftData]
  with ActorLogging
{

  import context._

  val mxTimeToWaitStopping = 500 milliseconds
  private var pendingPassengerRequests: Vector[NextStop] = Vector.empty
  private var currentFloorID = 0 // Always start at Ground Floor



  val timeToReachNextFloor = 1000 millis  // up  or down, same time taken

  private val dontCare: StateFunction = { /* ... */ }

  private val powerYourselfOff: StateFunction = { /* ... */ }

  private val powerYourselfOn: StateFunction = { /* ... */ }

  private val beReady: StateFunction = { /* ... */ }

  private val moveToWaitingPassenger: StateFunction = { /* ... */ }

  private val transportPassengerToDest: StateFunction = {/* ... */ }

  private val actWhenStoppedForLongEnough: StateFunction = {
    case Event(StateTimeout,_)   =>
      if (this.pendingPassengerRequests isEmpty) {
        println("timeout in Stopped, no passenger requests pending")
        goto (Stopped)
      }
      else {
        println("timeout in Stopped, moving to floor(" + this.pendingPassengerRequests.head + ")")
        simulateMovementTo(this.pendingPassengerRequests.head)
        goto(Moving)
      }
  }

  startWith(PoweredOff,InitialData)

  when (PoweredOff) (powerYourselfOn orElse
                     dontCare)

  when (PoweredOn)  (powerYourselfOff orElse
                     beReady orElse
                     dontCare)

  when (Ready)      (moveToWaitingPassenger   orElse
                     transportPassengerToDest )


  when (Stopped)   (actWhenStoppedForLongEnough orElse
                    moveToWaitingPassenger      orElse
                    transportPassengerToDest    )

  when (Moving)              {
    case Event(ReachedFloor(floorID, PurposeOfMovement.ToWelcomeInAnWaitingPassenger),_) =>
      currentFloorID = pendingPassengerRequests.head.floorID
      pendingPassengerRequests = pendingPassengerRequests.tail
      goto (Stopped) forMax(this.mxTimeToWaitStopping)

    case Event(ReachedFloor(floorID,PurposeOfMovement.ToAllowATransportedPassengerAlight),_) =>
      currentFloorID = pendingPassengerRequests.head.floorID
      pendingPassengerRequests = pendingPassengerRequests.tail
      goto (Stopped) forMax(this.mxTimeToWaitStopping)

   // .... Other events
  }

  whenUnhandled {
    // Event handlers...
  }

  onTransition {
    case Stopped -> Stopped => {
      println("Remaining in Stopped ...")
    }
  }

  // Rest of the Actor
```

I have pruned unnecessary parts, because the main point is this:
When the actor receives a

```
Event(ReachedFloor(floorID, PurposeOfMovement.ToWelcomeInAnWaitingPassenger),_)
```

when it is in the Moving state, it switches to Stopping state, with a specified timeout. When that timer fires while the FSM is Stopped, the handler that is supposed to execute, is named (shown above too):

```
actWhenStoppedForLongEnough
```

Here, I am checking a certain exit condition, and if I am not happy, I am switching back to same Stopped state again. I am using *goto()* now, but the original code had *stay()*.

I have set up a *onTransition* block too (shown above again), to prove that the transition indeed does happen.

```
onTransition {
    case Stopped -> Stopped => {
      println("Remaining in Stopped ...")
    }
  }
```

When I run the code, the *println* statement is not executed, at all.

I also have a testcode; the relevant testcase is this:

```
var carriage: ActorRef = _

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()

    carriage = TestActorRef(Props(new LiftCarriageWithMovingState))
    carriage ! SubscribeTransitionCallBack(testActor)
  }

  "A LiftCarriage" must {
    "be ready, when it settles down after being PoweredOn" in {

      expectMsg(Duration(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), new CurrentState(carriage,PoweredOff))
      carriage ! InstructedToPowerOn
      expectMsg (new Transition(carriage,PoweredOff,PoweredOn))
      carriage ! BeReady
      expectMsg((new Transition(carriage,PoweredOn,Ready)))
    }

    "move to where a passenger is waiting, if ready" in {
      carriage ! ReportCurrentFloor
      expectMsg(StoppedAt(0))
      carriage ! PassengerIsWaitingAt(3)
      expectMsg(new Transition(carriage,Ready,Moving))
      expectMsg(Duration(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), new Transition(carriage,Moving, Stopped))
      carriage ! ReportCurrentFloor
      expectMsg(StoppedAt(3))

    }
    "let a passenger in and transport her to her destination" in {
      carriage ! ReportCurrentFloor
      expectMsg(StoppedAt(3))
      carriage ! PassengerRequestsATransportTo(Vector(7))
      expectMsg(new Transition(carriage,Stopped,Moving))
      expectMsg(Duration(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), new Transition(carriage,Moving,Stopped))
      carriage ! ReportCurrentFloor
      expectMsg(StoppedAt(7))

      // This always times out and fails.
      expectMsg(Duration(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), new Transition(carriage,Stopped,Stopped)) 

    }
```

I am trying to think hard as to if and where the gap in my understanding lies, but failing. Any hints?

Here's the *build.sbt*:

```
name := """akka-sample-fsm-scala"""

version := "2.4"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.4.12",
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.11
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.1.3",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-testkit_2.11,
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.3.15"
)
```

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316409/akka-fsm-test-multiple-state-transitions?s=1%7C3.5999) - which is quite similar to mine - has been asked earlier, but I don't see any responses. May be, the answer has been found already but not yet shared.

Comment: There is test coverage for transitioning to the same state triggering onTransition [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/4a7cd147313404eb8137e56163e54f06c23640d0/akka-actor-tests/src/test/scala/akka/actor/FSMTransitionSpec.scala#L119) it was changed before Akka 2.4.0 was released (in ticket [13970](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/13970))

Can't see anything obviously wrong with your code, the only thing
 that is odd as far as I can see is that you are running an old version of `akka-testkit` together with current `akka-actor` maybe this has something to do with your problem?

Comment: Not sure if a clarification here helps anyone. I didn't respond to @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219125/johanandren either (my sincere apologies, I was discourteous). Here's what I have found on Akka documentation and this seems to my question (continued...)

Comment: '' '..Please note that a state change includes the action of performing an goto(S), while already being state S. In that case the monitoring actor will be notified with an Transition(ref,S,S) message. This may be useful if your FSM should react on all (also same-state) transitions. In case you’d rather not emit events for same-state transitions use stay() instead of goto(S)...'